# SQL Server 2008 Datetime field overflow

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-express

I am using C# to interface with a SQL database. the database has a DateTime field. When I try to write a DateTime object from C#, I get the following error:

> ERROR [22008] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Datetime field overflow

I found this on the topic:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqldataaccess/thread/ac1b5a6d-5e64-4603-9c92-b75ba4e51bf2/

Is there any manipulation I can do to my DateTime object on the C# side?

**EDITS**
I am trying to add DateTime.MinValue

Comment: Pls post the code you're using

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you are just passing in a bad date. For example, DateTime.MinValue is outside the accepted range for SQL Server datetime values by about 1600 years.

By the way, you shouldn't be using ODBC for C# to SQL Server communication. Using System.Data.SqlClient will give you much better performance.

Comment: wow, this was exactly the problem. I was trying to put in DateTime.MinValue. i bow in respect.

Answer (score 4):

The .NET DateTime object has a bigger range than the SQL date/time field.

In your data access layer, anytime your writing a date to the database, ensure that is inside the rate of SqlDateTime.MinValue and SqlDateTime.MaxValue.

Answer (score 2):

I'm quiet sure, your .NET DateTime is not initialized, what means it is "0000-01-01" and this is not a valid value for SQL Server DATETIME and *often* not a desired value ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Change all your datetime columns to datetime2 type. Generate the sql scripts using the query below.

```
select distinct concat('alter table ', table_name, ' alter column ',  column_name, ' datetime2 ', 
case when(is_nullable = 'NO') then ' NOT ' else '' end, ' NULL;') 
from information_schema.columns where data_type = 'datetime';
```